# Solr/Tika Extract Fails NoSuchMethodError, Solr 3.6, Tika 1.0, Jboss 5.0.1

Tags: solr, jboss, apache-tika

We have a multicore SOLR 3.6 install inside JBOSS with TIKA extract capability.  This is a new install on a Windows 2008 R2 VM.  This exact setup has worked on many many other deployements.  HEre is the stack trace when "extract" is called:

2013-01-31 08:52:51,908 SEVERE [org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tika.config.TikaConfig.(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)V
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler.getDefaultConfig(ExtractingRequestHandler.java:136)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler.inform(ExtractingRequestHandler.java:95)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.getWrappedHandler(RequestHandlers.java:255)
    at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handleRequest(RequestHandlers.java:242)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Comment: It looks like you might have two copies of Tika on your classpath, and old one and a new one. Can you check?

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue, getting NoSuchMethodErrors.  Turned out I had an old version of metadata-extractor.jar on my classpath, which was conflicting with the one in tika.jar.  If you can find the specific jar that's throwing the exception, you might have a version conflict.